# Get HTML from pipe

Tags: javascript, angular

How to bind HTML to an attribute/property of an element without Angular automagically breaking it by escaping?

Example:

```
<input type="text" [placeholder]="'test' | translate | async">
```

I also tried variants with `{{}}` and `attr.`, everything was broken in a same way.

I am getting correct (unescaped) data from `translate` pipe (and from whole pipe as well - checked by piping it into `json` pipe).

I found some workarounds with `innerHtml`, but those apparently can't be used in this case.

Comment: What HTML do you want to bind to `placeholder`?  Does it work when you add it directly to the DOM without using Angular binding?

Comment: HTML entities. Yes, it did work when entered directly.